# Is there a way to count number of files in which errors occure during the building process using Ninja/Cmake?

Tags: cmake, build, compilation, ninja

I want to count all the files with the building errors, while using Ninja/Cmake, is there a way to this?

Comment: You can use `ninja -k0` to make it keep going even after encountering errors and once it is done run it again to see the remaining number of steps. But that only gives an upper bound on the number of files with errors, some of the errors could be the result of previous steps failing. But I have to ask, why do you need that number anyway? If at least one file is broken your project won't build. It's not like you can try to reduce the number of errors on the side while also working on other stuff like you could with warnings where you'd make it a build failure in CI if the number increases.

Comment: @Corristo thanks for the answer. I need time estimation for the project I'm currently working on and one of the way to estimate time is to see how many files are broken.

Comment: @Corristo even I use ninja -k0 build stops at on moment, it's saying that it can't continue due to the previous errors.

Comment: Are you building shared libraries or generate source files during the build? Because then Ninja might not continue because the dependencies are not met. You may need to configure the CMake project with [CMAKE_OPTIMIZE_DEPENDNCIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES.html#variable:CMAKE_OPTIMIZE_DEPENDENCIES) turned on (you need CMake 3.19 for that) and build static libraries instead to continue further.